# Microsoft Defender: extract Automatic log upload data

Tags: logging, syslog, azure-networking

Is there a way to extract this automatic log upload table from defender:

[image: automatic log upload]

my goal is to use this information to aid in responding to the System alert: Cloud Discovery automatic log upload error alert in Defender:
[image]

which is misfiring due to two log collectors being used for the same data source. which can be verified with the table in automatic log upload.

Im open to any suggestions.

to get to the automatic upload page in defender:
[image]

Answer (score 0):

You could see if you can query it with a kusto query in advanced hunting.
And then you can export the results of that query to csv file.
But I'm not sure if there is a table for this in advanced hunting (Defender XDR) , you could check this one
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoft-365/security/defender/advanced-hunting-cloudappevents-table?view=o365-worldwide